# Query for blob images taking 20+ seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

- Images Table - 298 Rows
- Page Table - 91 rows
- Site Table = 10 rows

Created a view with images where Pages that have PageTypeID = 1

Example of view:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | RecordedDT              | RecordedUET                    | Image     | SiteID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  22 | 2021-02-03 11:38:37.843|      1612352317                |  blobimage |    2 
|  23 | 2021-02-03 11:38:38.310|      1612352318                |  blobimage |    2
|  24 | 2021-02-03 11:38:38.543|      1612352318                |  blobimage |    2 
|  25 | 2021-02-03 12:07:18.263|      1612354038                |  blobimage |    2
|  26 | 2021-02-03 12:07:18.740|      1612354038                |  blobimage |    2 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The view returns all 108 rows in 2 seconds (which is fine)
The issue is in the code the page is taking 20+ seconds to load

```
    private void GetCarouselImages()
    {
        var imgs = db.CarouselImages
                    .ToList();

        rCarousel.DataSource = imgs;
        rCarousel.DataBind();
    }


    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >  
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">  
            <asp:Repeater ID="rCarousel" runat="server">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <div class="carousel-item <%#GetActiveClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">  
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-100 h-100">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="<%#Eval("RecordedUET")%>" src="<%# GetImage(Eval("Image")) %>" />  
                            </div>
                    </div>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:Repeater>  
        </div>
```

I know that the images have to use the GetImage class from the eval but I've timed just the querying using the db.CarouselImages and that is what is taking up the majority of the time.

GetImage class if you need it:

```
    public string GetImage(object img)
    {
        return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])img);
    }
```

Comment: How big is each image?

Comment: All different sizes but all below 250kb and average around 110kb

Comment: So how long do you think it should take to base64 encode 300 images, totalling 33MB, and return and return 44MB of base64 encoded text? Used to be we'd sweat over web pages returning more than 1MB, including Javascript, style and images.

Comment: You can take the help of lazy loading images. instead of loading original image load a thumbnail and load images one by one.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning amen; had an opportunity to use our very old company website recently that was webforms, direct sql, minimal js/imagery and small page focused. Compared to the new massively overengineered, EF driven N+morethanitshouldbe tier backend, stuffed full of graphics and X mb of JS single page app they had built, that old barebones site was lightning fast(has no loading spinners because it doesn't need them), and more functional. But it looks awful. Funny how things change, and that people are more likely to think that something flash looking is high quality (and wait for it).

Comment: Thanks for the input all, reduced the size of the view to top 10 by date DESC. The carousel is for a customer portal to show them recent updates that are stored as images so realistically over 10 images is overkill anyway.

Going to look into some lazy loading now because even though its much qucker now a carousel doesn't realistically need to have all the images immediately.